# Bound on gcd of two integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

Well this is a problem I was fiddling with. I came up with it but it probably is not original.

> Suppose $a\in \mathbb{N}$ is not a perfect square. Then show that :
>   $$\text{gcd}(n,\lfloor{n\sqrt{a}}\rfloor)\le c\sqrt n\tag{1}$$ Where $c=\sqrt[4]{4a}$ and P.S. it is the best constant, when $ax^2-y^2=1$ admits a solution.

Now I have a couple questions.

- When $ax^2-y^2=1$ has no solution, what could be the best constant $c$ in $(1)$ then?
- What about when $\dfrac{\text{gcd}(n,\lfloor{n\alpha}\rfloor)}{\sqrt n}$we have a irrational number $\alpha$ which is not a quadratic surd. For example, $\pi,\sqrt[3]{2}$ etc?

Any references or solutions would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: For the first question, the answer probably depends upon the smallest value of $|ax^2-y^2|$.

Comment: Have you tried computing, say, $n^{-1/2}\gcd(n,[n\sqrt3])$ for $n$ up to a zillion to see what kinds of values you get?

Comment: Having computed up to 100,000, I'm convinced that the best $c$ for $\sqrt3$ is $\root4\of3$.

Answer (score 10):

For the second question, if $b = \sqrt{a}$ is an irrational number with very good rational approximations, there won't be an upper bound.  For example, if 
$$ \dfrac{p}{q} + \dfrac{1}{q^r} > b > \dfrac{p}{q}$$
for coprime positive integers $p,q$ and integer $r>1$, then taking $n=q^r$ we have $\lfloor n b \rfloor = p q^{r-1}$ and 
$\gcd(\lfloor n b \rfloor, n) = q^{r-1} = n^{1-1/r}$.  For example, you could take
$$b = \sum_{j=0}^\infty 2^{-(r+1)^j}$$ 
and have this with $q = 2^{(r+1)^m}$ for all positive integers $m$.

Of course, Roth's theorem says for an algebraic number $b$ there will be only finitely many such $q$.

EDIT: Conversely, suppose $\gcd(\lfloor nb \rfloor, n) = g$, with $n=gu$ and $\lfloor nb \rfloor = g v$ for coprime positive integers $u$,$v$.  Thus
$$ \dfrac{v}{u} + \dfrac{1}{gu} > b > \dfrac{v}{u}$$
If $g > 2 u$, i.e. $g > \sqrt{2n}$, then $v/u$ must be a convergent of the
continued fraction for $b$.  Moreover, if we have a bound $a_k < M$ for the elements $a_k$ of this continued fraction, then  $gu < (M+ 2) u^2$ so
that $g < \sqrt{(M+2) n}$.

EDIT: In the case $b = \sqrt{3}$, the convergents of the continued fraction that are less than $b$ 
are $v_k/u_k$ where $u_k$ and $v_k$ both satisfy the recurrence
$a_{k+2} = 4 a_{k+1} - a_k$, with $v_1 = 1$, $v_2 = 5$ while $u_1 = 1$, $u_2 = 3$, and $3 u_k^2 - v_k^2 = 2$.  We can then take
$$ \eqalign{g &= \left \lfloor \dfrac{1}{u_k \sqrt{3} - v_k}\right \rfloor =  \left \lfloor \dfrac{u_k \sqrt{3} + v_k}{2}\right \rfloor \approx \dfrac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2} (2+\sqrt{3})^k\cr  
 n &= g u_k \approx \left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}-\dfrac{1}{2}\right) (2 + \sqrt{3})^{2k}\cr
\dfrac{g}{\sqrt{n}} &\approx 3^{1/4}}$$

EDIT: A similar calculation for the case $b = \sqrt{7}$ seems to yield
$g/\sqrt{n} \approx (28/9)^{1/4}$

Answer (score 10):

Robert Israel's nice answer above already points to what happens if there are very good rational approximations to the irrational number $\alpha$.  Let me just address the first question when $\alpha =\sqrt{a}$ is a quadratic irrational (with $a$ being a non-square natural number).  Let $k$ be the least positive number that can be expressed as $ax^2-y^2$.  Then the best constant in the bound for the gcd is $\sqrt{2\sqrt{a}/k}$.

To see this, suppose $g=(n,\lfloor n\alpha \rfloor)$, and write $n=gv$ and $\lfloor n\alpha \rfloor =gu$.  Then 
$$ 
\frac{1}{n} > \alpha -\frac{u}{v} > 0,
$$ 
and multiplying both sides by $\alpha+u/v \le 2\alpha$ we get 
$$ 
\frac{2\alpha}{n} \ge \alpha^2 -\frac{u^2}{v^2} \ge \frac{k}{v^2},
$$ 
since $k$ is the smallest positive number of the form $a x^2- y^2$.  Since $v=n/g$, we conclude that 
$$ 
g^2 \le \frac{2\alpha}{n} \frac{n^2}{k} = \frac{2\alpha n}{k},
$$ 
which is the claimed bound.

To see that this bound is asymptotically attained, take a solution to $ax^2 -y^2 =k$ and by multiplying by a solution to the Pell equation $x^2-ay^2=1$ we can find a solution to $ax^2 -y^2 =k$ with $x$ and $y$ arbitrarily large.  Further such $x$ and $y$ may be assumed to be coprime by the minimality of $k$.   For such a choice we know that 
$$ 
\alpha - \frac{y}{x} \approx \frac{k}{2\alpha x^2}, 
$$ 
and choosing $n= x \lfloor (1-\epsilon) 2\alpha x/k\rfloor$ produces a large gcd for $n$ and $\lfloor n\alpha\rfloor$.

Finally the negative Pell equation $ax^2-y^2=1$ has been extensively studied, and still remains not fully understood.  See for example this impressive recent paper of [Fouvry and Kluners](http://www.math.uni-duesseldorf.de/~klueners/pell.pdf) in Annals.  It may also be interesting to note that there do exist $a$ for which $k$ is essentially as large as possible:  namely take $a$ of the form $b(b+2)$ and then the corresponding $k$ is $2b$.  (One can see this from the fact that the continued fraction expansion for $\sqrt{b(b+2)}$ is $[b;1,2b,1,2b,\ldots]$.)